# .htaccess 301 Redirect dynamic .cfm pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic

I have pages indexed by Google such as sample.com/product-detail.cfm?id=532323.  There are a lot of these pages.  These pages no longer exist and I would like to redirect all of them to the home page of our new site. Can anyone suggest how to redirect all of the pages without having to do each one individually?

Comment: Do you want all requests for the `/product-detail.cfm` to be redirected or only a set of `id` numbers?

Comment: All of them should go to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

> All of them should go to the home page

Then you can just check for `/product-detail.cfm` and ignore the `id=` param in the query string. You can do this with either mod_alias or mod_rewrite by adding these directives in the htaccess file in your document root:

Using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /product-detail.cfm /
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product-detail.cfm$ / [L,R=301]
```